# Fiddler Proxy Not Working with Android Lollipop Emulator

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, fiddler

I'm attempting to view network traffic from my lollipop emulator. I've followed the directions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2013/04/03/configuring-fiddler-to-be-a-proxy-for-android-emulators.aspx) and was able to navigate to my computer's ip with the fiddler port and install the root certificate (i.e. :8888/FiddlerRoot.cer) however I'm not seeing any traffic in Fiddler from the browser app.

I installed a KitKat emulator and followed the same instructions with success. So why doesn't the lollipop emulator work? What's changed in Android 5.0.1?

Answer (score 12):

Enable Air-plane mode and then disable!
It worked for me!

Comment: Though my issue was a bit different (I did not use https, but fiddler still didn't work), this simple step resolved it!

Answer (score 2):

To view HTTPS traffic in Fiddler on Lollipop and newer, you need to add the FiddlerRoot certificate (`DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot`) to the system list of CAs otherwise it simply won't work.

You need to have the CertMaker for iOS and Android installed because the default SSL certificate does not work properly on iOS/Android. It can be downloaded from the Fiddler Add-ons page:
http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons

After generating a (new?) root certificate open the .cer in the stock browser or Chrome (Firefox uses its own certificate system thus doesn't install to Android itself) and install the certificate for "VPN and apps" and name it `Fiddler` or whatever you want.

The certificate will be located in `/data/misc/user/0/cacerts-added/`.
Remount `/system` R/W as root if you haven't already (`mount -o remount,rw /system`).
Move the .0 file to `/system/etc/security/cacerts/` and chmod the file to `644`.

Reboot, and you should see HTTPS traffic from Android.